# How do you exclude the connections between mechanical shaker and specimen?

Tags: vibration, product-testing

to apply any kind of vibration, shock input using a mechanical shaker to any specimen, you first need to connect the speciment to the shaker, that sometimes needs some connectors that could weight as much as the specimen.

This means that the shaker, would need to apply more force to move the specimen ( like in case of imposed displacement). How is the effect of the excessive connector omittable ?

Comment: Use a load cell to measure the force applied to the object being tested. The fact that the shaker needs to provide more force, to also move itself, is then irrelevant.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? a series of controlled impacts? a sinusoidal force profile? a displacement-vs-time profile?  is the specimen anchored to something else?

Comment: The specimen is clamped to the other side, and sinusoidal is the input. If I add more connectors or heavier ones, I assume more force is needed since the mass inertia increases

Comment: " I assume more force is needed" - not necessarily, if the extra mass changes the resonant frequencies of the total system.